# Track changes inside a class using a dict

Tags: python

I want to send instructions to a method as a pickleable object, then have that make changes. (Think track changes).

Current method:

1. I define a set of instructions:

   ```
   instructions = {
       0: {
           'function': 'do_something_func',
           'kwargs': {
               'a':22,
               'b':'hello,  
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Inside my class I run the following:

   ```
   for step, transformation in self.instructions.items():
       eval('self.' + transformation['function'])(**transformation['kwargs'])
   ```

Generally, whenever `eval` is used, it's unsafe and wrong. This also feels like a problem people would have solved.

So, what is the "right" way to do this? Rough criteria:

- Allow me to track and store a set of instructions (so I can reverse if required)
- Doesn't expose vulnerabilities.
- Scalable to ~100 transformations max.
- Human readable instructions if possible / easy to develop.
- I'm quite flexible on how these instructions are stored, I have initialy thought of using a yaml file, but gets more tricky whne using python specific arguments - e.g. `numpy.nan`

Comment: `getattr(self, transformation['function'])(**transformation['kwargs'])`…?!

Comment: @deceze Beautiful - thank you! Happy to delete this or keep it up as closed for searchability reasons? Also +1 for finding a duplicate from 12 years ago :D